# Prove that $\phi$ is injective by showing the kernel is trivial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

> Let $r$ and $s$ be the generator $Q_8$ described in Section $5$. Let $\phi$ be the map from $Q_8$ to $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ defined on generators by
> $$
> \phi(r) = \begin{pmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{pmatrix}
> \text{ and }
> \phi(s) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
> $$
> which extends to a homomorphism. Prove that $\phi$ is injective.

Typically I would let $a,b\in Q_8$, such that $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$, and then show that $a=b$. However, I was reading only that you can prove injectivity by showing the $\ker\phi=e_{\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})}=I$. Now I don't typically use the kernel so can someone give me some pointers on how to go about this question and future ones of this kind?

Comment: Instead of assuming $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$ you start by assuming that $\phi(x)=I$ and then you work your way backwards until (hopefully) you deduce that necessarily $x=e$ (here $I$ is the identity matrix and $e$ the identity element in $Q_8$).

Comment: @mrtaurho Ahhh I see. So when I was working it out I started computing the determinant of $\phi(x)$ where $x=i^aj^b$ and setting it equal to 1. Comparing the $\det(\phi(i))$ and $\det(\phi(j))$ I get both are 1, which implies $\det(\phi(i)^a)$ and $\det(\phi(j)^b)$ both are 1. But how does this help me? Do I need to use the fact that the order of $\phi(i)$ and $\phi(j)$ is 4?

Comment: Computing the determinant won't bring you that far I suppose: there are many, many matrices with determinant $1$ which aren't the identity matrix (this subgroup has even it's own name...). But yeah, the basic idea is to observe that the images of  the generators $r$ and $s$ aren't the identity (obviously) and that the same holds for all their combinations, i.e. $\phi(r^as^b)$. For this it will be of use that $r^4=s^4=e$, indeed. However, I don't see some kind of trick for avoiding to compute at least the images explictely *Ben Grossmann* mentions in his answer ($8$ is really small...).

Comment: I guess computing individually is the approach for the problem. Grrrr. I just did want to do multiple computations.

Comment: I feel you :) But, as good as general methods are: sometimes they don't apply or are simply an overkill for a problem as simple as this. There isn't really much more to say about the general case than I did in my first comment. The identification *injective if and only if trivial kernel* is very useful and something to keep in mind, but not really helpful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have read is correct as a general approach, but because $Q_8$ is such a small group, it's better to simply list elements of the form $\phi(q)$ for $q \in Q_8$.

In fact, I recommend the following: compute
$$
\phi(r^2)= \phi(r)^2 = \pmatrix{-1&0\\0&-1}, \\
\phi(r^3) = \phi(r^2) \cdot \phi(r) = \pmatrix{i & 0\\0&-i},\\
\phi(s^3) = \phi(s^2) \cdot \phi(s) = \phi(r^2) \cdot \phi(s) = \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0},\\
\phi(rs) = \phi(r) \cdot \phi(s) = \pmatrix{0&-i\\i & 0},\\
\phi((rs)^3) = \phi((rs)^2) \cdot \phi(rs) = \phi(r^2) \cdot \phi(rs) = \pmatrix{0&i\\-i&0}.
$$
Because $\phi$ is a homomorphism, $\phi(1)$ must be the identity matrix. With this, you will have shown that $\phi$ maps the elements of $Q_8$ to distinct elements and is therefore indeed injective.

---

Proof that $(rs)^2 = r^2$: note that
$$
(rs)^2 = (rsr)s = ss = s^2 = r^2.
$$

Comment: Sure. But this question ask to use the generators $r$ and $s$.

Comment: @UsernameUnknown We do use those generators. For example, $\phi(-1) = \phi(r)^2$.

Comment: @UsernameUnknown See my latest edit.

Comment: Why don't you have (for example) $rs^3$ as an element?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Note that
$$
rs^3 = rs^2s = rr^2s = r^2 \cdot rs
$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that equation. That it is just a repeat of a previous element?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Yes that's exactly the point. $Q_8$ has $8$ distinct elements, and we have accounted for each of these.

Comment: Oh duh. Thank you for your help!!!